# Why is the placeholder not set properly in hikari.data-source-properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp, spring-cloud-config

I am setting the `hikari.data-source-properties` with a placeholder, but the placeholder value does not get substituted. It is a spring-boot 2.1.4.RELEASE based application. My intention is to set the Session properties so the DBAs can identify my application. Currently I get a default `JDBC Thin Client` for my connection when I run `SELECT PROGRAM FROM V$SESSION` from the DB

Below is what I have in my `application.yml` file

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@machine:1521:service_name"
        driver-class-name: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        hikari.data-source-properties:
            v$session.program:${spring.application.name}
```

Below is what I have in my `bootstrap.yml` file

```
spring:
    application:
        name: ms-db-service
```

When I query the Oracle DB, I notice that the value for program is literally `${spring.application.name}`, instead of the expected value `ms-db-service`

**I have tried the below, with same logical result:**

- Tried redefining the `spring.application.name` again in the `application.yml`
- Tried using a different locally defined key `${name}`
- Added the following bean

```
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

- Tried specifying the property as such: `spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties: v$session.program=${spring.application.name}`

**I tried the below items to gain more knowledge of the situation:**

- I tried using a placeholder for `spring.datasource.url` and that worked fine
- I tried to read the value manually using the below code, and that shows the correct values: `@Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties}") String propVal;`

My conclusion is that HikariCp reads these values before the placeholder substitution is done. I don't understand the relative timing of when the substitution and datasource bean creation happen in the spring-boot bean life-cycle

I am trying to avoid using a `bean` for hikaricp datasource (not sure if that will even solve the issue), as I don't want to manually build the whole datasource as hikari supports huge number of properties.

So, how can I set the `spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties` in application.yml using a placeholder. And, is there any other way to assign `spring.application.name` to identify my current db connection?

Comment: have you figured it out yet please ? I am struggling with the same problem...

Comment: @Patrik.Turcaj I haven't found any solution for this issue. You should check if creating a datasource manually in a bean method will work - I don't recall what was the result of that experiment for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        "[v$session.program]": ${spring.application.name}
```